# Visual Studio: Find out, if the app is "currently" in debug-mode programmatically

Tags: android, visual-studio

I'd like to run some code specifically only when the app is set to be in debug mode, not in release mode. The reson is just that some animations get skipped, so that I dont have to sit through them all the time when just debugging something that would come after the animations.
Some pseudo-code of what I want to achieve:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    BookOfLife.Helpers.Constants.WIDTHOFSCREEN = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
    BookOfLife.Helpers.Constants.HEIGHTOFSCREEN = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;

    this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_ReadAsset);

    if (this.Application.IsInDebugMode) {
        BackroundThreadding();
    } else {
        StartAnimtions();
    }

}
```

I think this is pretty much self-explainatory. 
How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    BackroundThreadding();
} else {
    StartAnimtions();
}
```

Comment: hi there. i tried it, but this doesnt exist in xamarin.